# AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: '<AppId>'

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .NET Core 2 app template that is configured to use Azure AD out of the box.

The configuration is:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "lautaroarinolive.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "67cb2dfd-ebd5-40d8-829b-378340981a17",
    "ClientId": "50819a7a-e018-4c1d-bf0a-18c8fce5c600",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

In my portal, I have an Azure app registration with the same id as `ClientId`. It has the reply URL `[APP-URL]/signin-oidc`.

[image: App registration in the Azure portal]

The localhost app works **only** if I set the reply URL to `[LocalhostURL]/signin-oidc`, even though I've learned that the configuration should not affect log in on localhost.

The Azure app does not work in any case.

In both apps when it doesn't work I get this error:

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the
>   reply urls configured for the application:
>   '50819a7a-e018-4c1d-bf0a-18c8fce5c600'

1. Is it correct that a localhost app should not need a configured reply URL?
2. Why do I get the "reply url not configured" error?

Comment: After publishing the application to azure web app service, The reply url should just be the `<appURL>/signin-oidc`. Is this a new AAD app ?

Comment: Yes its new. I havent changed anything.

Comment: It's weird. Which sample are you using?  I will do a deep test for this.

Comment: Thank you! I chose Net Core 2 MVC Application With Authentication set to work, single organization.

Comment: Oh it wasnt possible i guess. Here is a dl link. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11fQ0UiQWELF7L4Z6aOsU1P_YCFsgHq0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169718/discussion-between-wayne-yang-msft-and-lautaro).

Comment: Have you reffered to this Sample:https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore

Comment: Do you mean if I have looked at it? No I haven’t. Should I use it as reference?

Comment: Yep, you can refer to this Sample to intergrate your Application with AAD.:-)

Comment: It looks very much like what comes out from creating a new template. I’ll give it a try though.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT I tried the project from Git you linked to me. 

I made  a new app in azure portal and registered it in AzureAD. I changed the replyURL accordingly, but for it to work i also had to change the App ID Uri which also is wrong by default. So now it works on Azure , yay! 

But it still wont work in my localhost. You said something about that localhost should not use HTTPS? It does by default though could that be a problem? Overall i get the impression that when login works in azure it doesnt work in localhost, and the other way around.

Comment: Yep, you should use HTTP for localhost, NOT htttps!

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Sorry my mistake. I was using http in the localhost. 

"http://localhost:61659/"

Comment: The project is too old and the source code is not available

Comment: @WayneYang this helped me ....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can refer to [**this Sample**](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore) to rebuild your .NET core App and publish to the Azure.

There are some NOTES you need to pay attention to :

1. you need to change the port from 5000 to the effective one. Currently, it should be 61659. So, when you do a test in your localhost, you can set the reply URL in the AAD App with `http://localhost:61659/signin-oidc`
2. Update these URLs if you configure the app for production use or If you publish the App to Azure Web App, you should change the Reply URL in both App config file and AAD Application to be `<AppURL>/signin-oidc`

For example, `https://www.contoso.com/signin-oidc` or `https://Myapp.azurewebsites.net/signout-oidc`.

Comment: Ok so its not possible to have it configured for localhost and Azure Web App at the same time?

Comment: Now it works. Both localhost and in azure. I added both reply URL:s.

In your example, i added both 
http://localhost:61659/signin-oidc
and
https://Myapp.azurewebsites.net/signout-oidc

and now i can login both online in azure app and in localhost.

Comment: Yep, you cannot add different domain in the reply URLs, but you can add  the localhost .When you publish your App to azure, you needn't to configure the localhost in Azure.If you also want to lgoin with localhost, you can just add localhost in the reply urls

Comment: Hi @whihathac , you can see the restriction here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations#restrictions-on-redirect-uris

Comment: This answer makes no sense. You dont say anywhere in the answer what file you need to change. I currently dont see any file that has a port.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem with a .NET 4.6.1 web application.
I had to configure the Reply URL for my app in azure similar to the accepted answer, however the callback url was different.

```
Select Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> <your app>
Select Settings -> Reply URLs
```

Add your apps URL + '/.auth/login/aad/callback'
For Example:
`https://somesite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`

Comment: I agree with your solution, '/.auth/login/aad/callback'

Comment: `/.auth/login/aad/callback` appears to be hardcoded redirect path AzureAD/Microsoft signin provider will redirect to on successful sign-in. If you don't have `https://${yoursite}/.auth/login/aad/callback` in your reply-urls, sign in with Microsoft online will throw error AADSTS50011.

Comment: Adding `https://${yoursite}/.auth/login/aad/callback` as the RedirectURI was the trick!

Answer (score 12):

Check your redirect uri in your Microsoft sign in page

***redirect_uri=https://localhost:8443/login***&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile&state=7GsiHb

[image]

**And make sure that you have added the same URI to redirect URI list in your registered application (Active Directory -> App Registration -> Your Application). As mentioned in other answers may need to change supported account type as "Multiple Organizations".**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just got the same error. My app is a .NET 5 ASP.NET Core app running in a Linux docker container inside of a web app. Troubleshooting using Fiddler has shown that in calls to login.microsoft.com the value of a redirect_uri query string variable was starting with "http://" and not with "https://" as I would expect despite my attempts to enforce TLS-only on the web app itself. That led to URL mismatch and to the error AADSTS50011.

Setting the environment variable ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED=true on the web app has fixed the issue. Microsoft has documented it here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/forwarded-headers-middleware-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-6/

Comment: This was the perfect answer to my issue. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);` must below the **Authentication configuration.**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "";
    options.ClientId = "";
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
    options.CallbackPath = "";
    options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
})
.AddCookie();
```

I was facing the same error due to having added `AddMvc()` before the `AddAuthentication()` extension method.

Answer (score 1):

In some case, azure to use the 'www'  on the url, even if you especific the url on the portal without 'www'. Use "https://www.mysite.co/signin-oidc" instead "https://mysite.co/signin-oidc" in your redirectUri variable.

Comment: This worked for me. I was searching for errors and followed every other step but this one helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Small thing, but at the Web Tenant, at custom domains settings HTTPS Only option should be turned on depending on URLs used by the site. I had the same problem, as at the login, the redrect_uri=http://sitename was concatenated instead of https. Enabling this option resolved my authentication issue.

Comment: Where is this option? I the azure portal?

Comment: Yes. At the web tentant, settings/custom domains HTTPS only setting can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are signing in from AAD you should use app-base-url/sigin-aad.

Answer (score 0):

If you use React- Native. Able to check the web portal: https://portal.azure.com/.

> iOS: {YOUR_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}://{YOUR_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}/ios/callback

> Android: {YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME}://{YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME}/android/callback

pls refer with image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqZzS.png)

Comment: Your image is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for me: in the Azure portal `https://portal.azure.com`, navigate to "app registrations" -> select your application -> "authentication" from the left sidebar menu -> "mobile and desktop applications" redirect URIs -> and click "Add URI" -> type the following

> ms-appx-web://microsoft.aad.brokerplugin/{Your_Application's_Client_ID}

Example: `ms-appx-web://microsoft.aad.brokerplugin/5r3257qe-7jci-3501-38k0-3791h90542m7`