# Azure App Service web app: Django + Microsoft login redirect HTTPS issue

Tags: django, https, azure-web-app-service, msal

Azure App registration web redirect URL (it's HTTPS) as below:
[image]

Using Azure App Service deployed the Django web app successfully:
[image]

the above deploying result shows http://, but in Azure web app web it shows https://, also could open the web app using https successfully with valid  as below:

[image]

But when the web app redirected to Microsoft site to login, it uses http:// again which doesn't match the https:// configured in App registration:

[image]

The MS authentication and redirection is handled by package `ms_identity_web`, code
provided from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-django-tutorial/tree/main/1-Authentication/sign-in

In development environment there is no issue since I use http://localhost:8000/auth/redirect as web redirect url in App registration.

My issue could be the same as this one: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71354132/redirect-url-does-not-match-on-azure), but it covered the URL details so not sure if it was the same http/https mismatching issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding the below into settings.py

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

reference: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-django-tutorial/issues/5