# Azure app sign-in failure - reply URL doesn't match because of trailing slash

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-proxy

After deploying my Azure AD integrated app to IIS I can't login anymore.

The app is configured on xxx.abc.com with the following settings in Azure AD
[image]

When I try to login by going to https://xxx.abc.com I get the following message:

> AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'https://xxx.abc.com/signin-oidc' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application 'XXXXX-118d-4041-8117-XXXXX'. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal. Navigate to https://aka.ms/redirectUriMismatchError to learn more about how to fix this. **More details: Reply address did not match because requested address had a trailing slash**.

Reading this error it makes me think the error is due to the trailing dash in the Azure AD configuration as shown in the image "https://xxx.abc.com/signin-oidc/". The thing is, if I try to remove the trailing dash it says "The path of the url does not end with '/'" and it doesn't allow me to save the change.

[image]

I've tried all kinds of variations of the urls but to no avail.

The current configuration does work (!) when debugging with Visual Studio at https://localhost:7098/.

Comment: Please check this MsDoc : [Azure App Service error: AADSTS50011: The reply address 'https://.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application: | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jpsanders/azure-app-service-error-aadsts50011-the-reply-address-http-azurewebsites-netsignin-oidc-does-not-match-the-reply-addresses-configured-for-the-application)

Comment: The article explains you have to copy the redirect url from the error message. That's not possible though as it's 'https://xxx.abc.com/signin-oidc' (notice, no trailing dash) which isn't allowed in Azure AD. I have to end the url with a trailing dash.

Comment: You can add redirect Uri with no trailing slash in the end. Please refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url)

Comment: It doens't seem to be possible. Please refer to the second image I just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem by adding a trailing dash to the callback path in appsettings.json

```
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc/"
```

Answer (score 0):

***The error " **`AADSTS50011`**" usually occurs if the redirect Uri application is redirected doesn't match the redirect Uri registered in the application.***

Make sure to deploy the **Azure web app in Azure Active Directory** and make sure to add the Uri:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> New Registration*

[image]

**Check whether the redirect Uri matches like below:**

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App -> Authentication*

[image]

Or copy the **redirect Uri** from the error message and add the copied redirect Uri in your Azure portal application and save.

Otherwise please try following this [**Microsoft QnA**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/567933/how-to-troubleshoot-the-error-aadsts5001134.html) by AmanpreetSingh-MSFT.

- Try updating the Uri as **`AppURL/signin-oidc`** as mentioned in this [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011686/aadsts50011-the-reply-url-specified-in-the-request-does-not-match-the-reply-url) by Wayne Yang.

***If still the issue persists***, **refer** the below links which might give you a pointer to solve the error:

[Identity Error AADSTS50011 Azure AD by Ben Murphy Dev Blog](https://benmurphy.uk/sitecore-identity-error-aadsts50011/)

[How to fix "AADSTS50011: The reply address does not match the reply addresses configured"by Antti K. Koskela](https://www.koskila.net/aadsts50011-the-reply-address-does-not-match-the-reply-addresses-configured/)